# what's difference multiple blank variables declare

Tags: javascript, object

literal object methods:

```
var objectA = {}; 
var objectB = {};
```

vs

```
var objectA = objectB = {};
```

constructor object methods:

```
var objectA = new Object();
var objectB = new Object();
```

vs

```
var objectA = objectB = new Object();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you do

```
var objectA = {}; 
var objectB = {};
```

or

```
var objectA = new Object();
var objectB = new Object();
```

**You are creating two different JavaScript objects** and they are referred by `objectA` and `objectB`. But when you do

```
var objectA = objectB = {};
```

or

```
var objectA = objectB = new Object();
```

**You are actually creating only one object** and making both `objectA` and `objectB` refer the same object.

You can confirm this by checking if both the objects are one and the same or not, like this

```
var objectA = {}, objectB = {};
console.log(objectA === objectB);
// false
var objectC = objectD = {};
console.log(objectC === objectD);
// true
```

**Note:**

```
var objectC = objectD = {};
```

will be evaluated like this

```
var objectC = (objectD = {});
```

That is why both `objectC` and `objectD` refer the same object.

**Important:** [As dfsq mentions in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887561/whats-difference-multiple-blank-variables-declare#comment44176205_27887588), in the last example, `objectD` will be leaked to the global scope. So, avoid using this pattern.

Comment: And to make this answer complete: one more important difference is that `var objectA = objectB = {};` code also leaks `objectB` into global scope. So this pattern should be avoided.

Comment: @dfsq I included a note about this in the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: could i think objectC and objectD are all links to the same {} object in global scope?

Answer (score 0):

The first approach creates an object and assigns a reference to it to a variable. Then it creates another object and assigns a reference to that to a different variable.

The second approach creates an object and assigns a reference to it to a variable. Then it assigns another reference to the same object to a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

These are the same; `{}` creates a new `Object`:

```
var a = {};
var b = new Object();
```

If you assign the *same instance of an object*, empty or otherwise, to two variables, they will both refer to the same instance.

```
var b;
var a = b = {}

a.Foo = 'foo';
// "foo"
alert(b.Foo);
```

If you create a different instance for each, they will refer to different instances:

```
var b = {};
var a = {};

a.Foo = 'foo';
// ""
alert(b.Foo);
```

If you do one of those chained assignments with a value type like an integer, that'll be different, in implementation dependent ways, but since integers have no properties you can alter, it's a non-issue. I spent some time with the C source for the old Netscape < 4 JavaScript engine back when they first released the source. Integers were stored in the pointer itself, left-shifted by one or two bits and tagged in the lowest order bits (allocated memory was aligned on four-byte boundaries so those two bits were always zero on a valid pointer). IIRC Gnu Common Lisp does it that way too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as `new Object()` and `{}` are concerned, both result in an Object *instance*.

As far as `var objA = objB = {}` is concerned, both `objA` and `objB` share the same reference to the Object *instance* but that is not the case when you assign them separately.

Answer (score 0):

**First case**

When you say this

```
var objectA = {}; 
var objectB = {};
```

or

```
var objectA = new Object();
var objectB = new Object();
```

You are creating two different objects. If you will compare both objects

```
objectA == objectB //return false
```

**Second Case**

When you say

```
var objectA = objectB = {};
```

or

```
var objectA = objectB = new Object();
```

here `objectA` and `objectB` both refer to same object. **Because first you are creating an object and assigning that to `objectA` and `objectB` so both will have the reference of created object.**

In this condition

```
objectA == objectB //return true
```

**Note:-**

If you want to create two objects with same reference, do it in two lines like bellow

```
var objectA = new Object();
var objectB = objectA;
```

Because you shouldn't mess your global scope unnecessarily.